# Devise + Omniauth redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

So I've attempted to add OmniAuth to my Rails app, which currently uses Devise + Pundit for authentication and authorization. I have added a "Log in with Facebook" button and configured it so it pops up a Facebook login window. However, after you submit that form, the app crashes with a "Too many redirects" error. I also think I might be misunderstanding something about the #passthru action on the users/auth/:provider route.

Here's the relevant routes:

```
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
```

And routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :movies
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Here's the console output that keeps printing on a loop:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook?code=AQAIAC2szE1y30Ob9o7SSHfu4KckM4OxBNa1UuzvjiNYqD93_mRMTcfE2Hz01ZSDVOzRJW0DxHMtRHIeWOJW6T2Uvfc4heeoM5cNVh6QXEQsokSOh0jfcFjFsWlyzj8SKZSS9Az-MwaaekwqrLrfvTYii2ibhbzadhoymD2omBcevmPvfQlnfGQolV7E78R_nD7YoEshNLQ3GejPqMXGbBgs4L3YFP3D-5B_rcIOmNYopnpERQTtpKep1Apv5OmqBGiJy-UWH9_cPPCtNMpBjPOjUeUGG9fzE4nzEoMvAZzDQj4LMBAxm0DWqFdetFQ34Eg&state=3d59887ccde2c2be1677f6f75010bf4a3eccc3021017ec89" for 71.212.102.26 at 2016-04-20 20:08:37 +0000
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook?code=AQAIAC2szE1y30Ob9o7SSHfu4KckM4OxBNa1UuzvjiNYqD93_mRMTcfE2Hz01ZSDVOzRJW0DxHMtRHIeWOJW6T2Uvfc4heeoM5cNVh6QXEQsokSOh0jfcFjFsWlyzj8SKZSS9Az-MwaaekwqrLrfvTYii2ibhbzadhoymD2omBcevmPvfQlnfGQolV7E78R_nD7YoEshNLQ3GejPqMXGbBgs4L3YFP3D-5B_rcIOmNYopnpERQTtpKep1Apv5OmqBGiJy-UWH9_cPPCtNMpBjPOjUeUGG9fzE4nzEoMvAZzDQj4LMBAxm0DWqFdetFQ34Eg&state=3d59887ccde2c2be1677f6f75010bf4a3eccc3021017ec89" for 71.212.102.26 at 2016-04-20 20:08:37 +0000
Cannot render console from 71.212.102.26! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Cannot render console from 71.212.102.26! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2016-04-20T20:08:37.157387 #20936]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
```